# What is the purpose of a signature file (*.SF) when signing a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, digital-signature, sign, jarsigner

As I learned from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html the procedure of signing jar file with jarsigner is following:

1. The manifest file is updated with a list of hashes for each file:

   Name: com/qarks/util/files/diff/ui/main/DiffMergeFrame.class
   SHA-256-Digest: GZgPXG9YnmVGXb+hFwnJF4im4hb/qixX2Gs+ZNpdGFU=

   Name: com/qarks/util/ui/swing/PrintManager.class
   SHA-256-Digest: cO6XolXrk5NlHBocDF0fzojlwSAKlDoGsY/jdJ0fzdY=
2. The signature file (*.SF) is created. It contains:

   - hash of manifest file
   - hash of main attributes in the manifest file
   - hashes of hashes for each file from the manifest file.
3. The signature block file (*.RSA, *.DSA) is created. It stores the digital signature of the *.SF signature file.

So, I'd like to know why do we need *.SF at all - why can't we just sign a manifest file, instead of *.SF file?

And also what's the purpose of having hashes of hashes in *.SF file (additional check? in what cases?)?

Answer (score 5):

Signature file (`.SF`) represents the signer of the `.jar` file - there can technically be more than one.

To answer your second question imagine a case where a `.jar` file is modified after it has already been signed. The `manifest` file would have been changed and therefore the hash in `.SF` (`*-Digest-Manifest`) would no longer match that of the current `.manifest` file.

However, if only new files were added to the `.jar` it would still pass validation, as the validation algorithm (among other things) looks at each entry in the `.SF` and validates the hashes against the respective entries in the `manifest` (new entries in the `manifest` would be ignored).

To sum it up, `.SF` is used to verify that none of the files, that were in the `.jar` at the moment of signing, have been changed.

You can read more about signature validation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Signature_Validation).